# How do schedutil tunables affect CPU frequency adjusting exactly?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Linux\Android's kernel `schedutil` governor has the following tunables depending on its version:

```
down_rate_limit_us
up_rate_limit_us
hispeed_load
hispeed_freq
target_loads
pl
```

It's not quite clear to me the meaning of those tunables even after reading its sources in `cpufreq_schedutil.c` due to heavy usage of data types denoting hardware in the code and lack of comments. Also, there's literally no documentation on Linux kernel websites\XDA on these tunables (or I'm too dumb to find one using Google despite the hours of researching).

Could someone explain how each `schedutil` tunable affects CPU frequency adjusting in detail, please?